# Hide the keyboard on Go Button for a editbox

Tags: ipad, keyboard, xpages

I'm developing a xpages mobile form to do a full-text search.
How can I hide the keyboard on a iPad, clicking Go Button when finish to write a text in a editbox and make a submit action?.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the keyboard with the *blur()* method of the input box:

```
XSP.getElementById('view:_id1:inputText1').blur();
```

view:_id1:inputText1 is the client side id of your input box